# new keystrokes in Terminal defined, but do nothing

Tags: terminal, keybindings

To move the insertion point backwards and forwards a word at a time, Terminal by default uses Option + left or right arrow.
Because my 101-key USB keyboard lacks an Option key, I'd like to use Control + left or right arrow, as is common in Linux.

So in Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard, I copied the Option entries to Control entries, \033f and \033b:

[image: terminal's profiles window]

But control+arrows still does nothing, from the USB keyboard or from the Macbook Pro laptop's own keyboard.

Even stranger, *alt* + arrows *does* move the insertion point wordwise.  (Oh, because Option maps to Alt.  Now I know.)

How can I make control+arrows do that?

Comment: just for the sake of argument ;-P you do realize that the ALT key maps to the Option key on a Mac?

Comment: The defaults for bash (not Terminal) are `Meta-f` and `Meta-b` to go forwards and backwards one word at a time.  `Meta` is your `Alt` key (you may have to enable "use option as meta key" in preferences.  I don't recommend remapping this because this is universal for bash across all platforms (Mac, Unix, BSD, even Linux).  Linux just does some weird non-standard things and this is one of them.